# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Paging help needed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Needed help again.
So I am currently working on ASP.NET Core 2.0 Paging and it's not working properly.

I followed the tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page

However, the thing is that the tutorial is using Entity Framework dateset or IQuery? I however is using List<>. Does anyone know how to solve this problem or convert my List into EF DataSet or something?

Controller Paginated.cs :

```
public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var count = await source.CountAsync();
    var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
    return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
    ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    var students = addList();

    ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    if (searchString != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;


    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name_desc":
            students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name).ToList();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (searchString != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
    int pageSize = 3;
    return View(await PaginatedList<Student>.CreateAsync(students.AsNoTracking(), page ?? 1, pageSize));
    // return View(PaginatedList<Student>(students, page ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

If you look at the code above, it only works if it is dataset retrieve from EF.

The CountAsync(), students.AsNoTracking() is not working because it is a List.

Anyone know what should I do?
Let me know if you need anything.

Thanks!

EDit:

```
public IQueryable<Student> addList()
{
    var studentList = new List<Student>();
    studentList.Add(new Student
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "David",
        ClassName = "Moria"
    });

    studentList.Add(new Student
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Jenny",
        ClassName = "Moria"
    });

    studentList.Add(new Student
    {
        Id = 3,
        Name = "Crystal",
        ClassName = "Moria"
    });

    studentList.Add(new Student
    {
        Id = 4,
        Name = "jenny",
        ClassName = "Moria"
    });

    studentList.Add(new Student
    {
        Id = 5,
        Name = "Andria",
        ClassName = "Moria"
    });

    studentList.Add(new Student
    {
        Id = 6,
        Name = "Sweet",
        ClassName = "Moria"
    });

    studentList.Add(new Student
    {
        Id = 7,
        Name = "Susan",
        ClassName = "Moria"
    });
    return studentList.AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: Instead of `CountAsync` you can just use the `Count` property. `AsNoTracking` only identifies how caching works, so you can leave that out.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks!, The thing is that if I leave out the AsNoTracking, I would have error "cannot convert from Generic.List<Models.Students> to System.Linq.IQueryable<Model.Students>'

Comment: Try `students.AsQueryable()` instead then. Did you type the name right though? Why is one `Models.Students` and the other one `Model.Students`?

Comment: What is your `addList()` method in `var students = addList();` doing? Are you saying that its `returns List<Student>` rather that `IQueryable<T>` and if so why?

Comment: You can of course change `IQueryable<T> source` to `IEnumerable<T> source` in the `CreateAsync` method, but your kind of defeating the purpose of paging is your downloading all records, and using async is pointless

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your help. I am just following the tutorial for the CreateAsync. I changed it to IQueryable however I got this error message "InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IEntityQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations."

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks Ron, the model. students is correct manage to change to AsQueryable as well. Just that I had this error InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IEntityQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations."

Comment: You still have not answered my question. What is your code for `addList()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just edited my post again to include the addList

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165018/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sarah).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `addList()` is just creating an in-memory set of hard coded data. There is no point using async methods (and it is actually degrading performance) or using `IQueryable` (your not querying an external data source).

I suggest rename your `addlist` method to something more meaningful, say `FetchStudents()`. Since your generating `List<Student>` in the method, it should return `IList<Student>`

```
public IList<Student> FetchStudents()
{
    ....
    return studentList;
}
```

Next change the `CreateAsync()` method to accept `IEnumerable<T>` and remove the async calls

```
public static PaginatedList<T> Create(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var count = source.Count();
    var items = source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

and finally modify the `Index()` method to

```
public IActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
    ....
    var students = FetchStudents();
    ....
    return View(PaginatedList<Student>.Create(students, page ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, How are you doing? Needed your help again. Do you know what should I do to modify the code that it can accept more than one searchString? What I mean is that if you look at the code now, currently it only accepts one searchString which is for "Name", however, I wanted to add another SearchString for "ClassName". So basically in the View will have 2 input Search field, if both are filled then I will show the student based on the name and className.

Comment: That should be easy enough - just add a `string className` parameter to your method, and a `<input>` in the view with the same name so it binds to the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's just that if you look at the code     ViewData["CurrentFilter"], this one only accept first search string, I am quite confuse on how to tweak it that it can accept two search string

Comment: Can I ask do you know what this mean?     if (searchString != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

Comment: Go to out [previous chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165018/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sarah) and I'll add some comments there.